# Combine 2 point clouds constructed from disparity map

Tags: opencv, point-clouds, disparity-mapping

I have a stereopair (2 perspective cameras) which is rotated and does not move. Using conventional opencv methods I found disparity maps and perspective projection matrix Q.

From this I constructed 2 point clouds with `reprojectImageTo3D()` for two different stereopair orientations. I do know the angles describing camera orientation for each cloud (disparity map).

My question is how to transform (rotate, translate) those clouds to get a match? What math is behind?

I thought naively that it would be sufficient just to do the rotation of the second cloud by inverse rotation angles, but it does not work both from practical and theoretical point of view. Any ideas?

Comment: translation and rotation is needed. in addition you should use ICP for fine-adjustment and maybe some fusion method like described in kinectFusion

Comment: I do understand that I need both, but what are details (puting aside fine refinement with ICP)?

Comment: have a look at homogeneous coordinates affine transformations to combine rotation and translation to a single transformation you cam apply to your points